# Query broke down and left me stranded in the woods

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to execute a query that deletes all files from the images table that do not exist in the filters tables. I am skipping 3,500 of the latest files in the database as to sort of "Trim" the table back to 3,500 + "X" amount of records in the filters table.

The filters table holds markers for the file, as well as the file id used in the images table.

The code will run on a cron job.

My Code:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `images` ORDER BY `id` DESC") or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $id = $row['id'];
    $file = $row['url'];

    $getId = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `filter` WHERE `img_id` = '".$id."'") or die(mysql_error());
    if(mysql_num_rows($getId) == 0){        
        $IdQue[] = $id;
        $FileQue[] = $file;
    }
}
for($i=3500; $i<$x; $i++){
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM `images` WHERE id='".$IdQue[$i]."' LIMIT 1") or die("line 18".mysql_error());
    unlink($FileQue[$i]) or die("file Not deleted");
}
echo ($i-3500)." files deleted.";
```

Output: 0 files deleted.

Database contents:

```
images table: 10,000 rows
filters table: 63 rows
```

Amount of rows in filters table that contain an images table id: 63
Execution time of php script: 4 seconds +/- 0.5 second

Relevant DB structure

- TABLE: images
- id
- url
- etc...
- TABLE: filter
- id
- img_id (CONTAINS ID FROM images table)
- etc...

Comment: Please edit and rephrase your question (title) to something meaningful. Since tag information doesn't belong in the title, remove `php` and `mysql` at a minimum, which leaves `Query broke down...`, and that has absolutely no meaning. Using a clear title helps attract people to the question who might be able to get you an answer. Thanks.

Comment: Where does the "$x" variable in the for loop come from?

Comment: It is from a counter.... That is no longer there... lol

Comment: It should still work even though the loop never terminates... Obvious edit is neccesary

Comment: I think the loop would never begin in the first place, maybe that is the reason it is not deleting any files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

building off of Brendan's answer, you can just build a [subquery](http://www.roseindia.net/mysql/mysql5/writing-subqueries.shtml). Your whole script could look just like:

```
$query = mysql_query(
   "DELETE FROM `images` WHERE `id` NOT IN (
       SELECT `id` from `filter`
    ) ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 3500,12340283492834
") or die(mysql_error());

printf("Files deleted: %d\n", mysql_affected_rows());
```

The subquery `` (SELECT `id` from `filter` LIMIT 3500,12340283492834) `` resolves first and returns a list of ids to the parent query to use in the `WHERE` clause. You then preserve the last 3500 rows by passing in an offset (so it skips the first 3500 rows, and then deletes the rest). Note the ugly `LIMIT 3500,12340283492834`... this is because MySQL does not support offsets without limits.

Once you're done, run a select query to get all your images-urls and then loop through the images on the filesystem and delete them if the filename isn't in the result array.

Comment: Unfortunately, `LIMIT 3500` isn't what we want, since we want to have the result be 3500 + filters left. I'm trying to think of how to do it but I'm pretty tired :\

Comment: This will remove the rows from the DB, but not the files on disk. Notice the unlink()call. (@TurboJ).

Comment: Say there is 10,000 records and I limit 3,500 then i still have 6,500 records right? What I need to do is keep 3,500 of the highest auto_incremented id's and delete the rest. So the LIMIT will vary.

Comment: @user1290323 You can also use basically this same query to get the list of files to delete (``SELECT `url` FROM ...`` instead of ``DELETE FROM ...``). You would need to use a transaction though.

Comment: how bout that unlink call? I am thinking... read filenames in directory compare with url field in DB and unlink accordingly... Any better suggestions as this seems inefficient

Comment: It might be a little inefficient (though using `scandir` or `glob` might make it faster). Put all the image urls in an array (grab everything from the DB after deleting) and then loop through each file and delete `if (!in_array(...))`. Test the speed. If it's too slow you can do the deleting first (same query, but switch DELETE WITH `SELECT `url`) and unlink each URL it returns.

Answer (score 1):

```
 for($i=3500; $i<$x; $i++){
```

This does not do anything if `$x < 3500`. You probably wanted:

```
 for($i=3500; $i<($x + 3500); $i++){
```

Re-reading the documentation about SQL `JOIN` would be a good idea, too.